# Keep Duplicates in XPath Query Result

Tags: xml, xpath, duplicates

Consider the following XML example:

```
<books category="cat1">
   <book id="1" ... />
   <book id="2" ... />
   <book id="3" ... />
</books>
```

If I use the XPath query `/books/book/parent::*/@category` I am expected to receive 
one row only:

```
cat1
```

However, how can the XPath query be modified to return

```
cat1
cat1
cat1
```

(meaning that I want to keep all duplicates).

Answer (score 4):

In **XPath 2.0** you could use a `for` loop:

```
for  $book in /books/book return $book/parent::*/@category
```

Answer (score 4):

The "/" operator in XPath automatically removes duplicates.

In XPath 1.0 there's a fundamental difficulty with your requirement: the only composite value supported in the data model is the node-set, and node-sets (being sets) cannot contain duplicates. So there's no such thing as a value containing duplicate nodes, and therefore no expression that will produce such a result.